# How do I compile to WASM in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, go, webpack, webassembly

I would like to know the "canonical way" to compile Go to WASM with webpack so that is available in a react app created with CRA.

So far I have tried the following:

1. Started a new react app with CRA.
2. Installed webpack-golang-wasm-async-loader via `yarn add --dev webpack-golang-wasm-async-loader` (https://github.com/aaronpowell/webpack-golang-wasm-async-loader)
3. Installed react-app-rewired via `yarn add --dev react-app-rewired` in order to edit the Webpack config without ejecting
4. Edited the `config-overrides.js` file with the following:

   ```
      const path = require('path');

      module.exports = function override(config, env) {
      const goExtensionRegExp = /\.go/;

      // add a dedicated loader for WASM
      config.module.rules.push({
          test: goExtensionRegExp,
          use: ['golang-wasm-async-loader']
      });

      config.node.fs = 'empty'

      return config;
    };
   ```

   to accord with the config instructions given in the loader [README](https://github.com/aaronpowell/webpack-golang-wasm-async-loader):

   ```
     module.exports = {
       ...
       module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.go/,
                    use: ['golang-wasm-async-loader']
                }
            ]
        },
        node: {
            fs: 'empty'
        }
   };
   ```
5. In my `App.js` file I have the following:

   ```
    import React from 'react';

    import wasm from './main.go'

    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';

    class App extends React.Component {

      async init() {
        const result = await wasm.add(1, 2);
        console.log(result);

        const someValue = await wasm.someValue();
        console.log(someValue);
      }

      render() {
        return <div>Hello world</div>;
      }
    }

    export default App;
   ```
6. In my `main.go` file I have the following:

   ```
   package main

   import (
        "strconv"
        "syscall/js"
        "github.com/aaronpowell/webpack-golang-wasm-async-loader/gobridge"
    )

    func add(i []js.Value) (interface{},error) {
        ret := 0

        for _, item := range i {
            val, _ := strconv.Atoi(item.String())
            ret += val
        }

        return ret, nil
    }

    func main() {
        c := make(chan struct{}, 0)

        gobridge.RegisterCallback("add", add)
        gobridge.RegisterValue("someValue", "Hello World")

        <-c
    }
   ```

My directory structure looks like the following:

```
    |- root
       |- node_modules
       |- public
       |- src
          |- App.css
          |- App.js
          |- App.test.js
          |- index.css
          |- index.js
          |- logo.svg
          |- main.go
          |...
       |...
       |- config-overrides.js
       |- package.json
```

Upon running `yarn start` I get the following error:

`./src/main.go Error: spawn undefined/bin/go ENOENT`

I would very much appreciate any help on how to get this to work, and I am open to using another approach, which is why I did not include the library name in the title.